# How get All Node Name in activit 7.0.0.0.SR1 standalone version

Tags: java, activiti

Actually, i am not used cloud version . currently we have used standalone version 7.0.0.SR1. Previously we get Activities from ProcessDefinitionEntity.java.

We simply write following line and get list of ActivityImpl ex...

List activityList = processDefinitionEntity.getActivities();

But in version 7.0.0.0.SR1 now ActivitiImpl was not there . so how we can get All NodeName of process defination. please suggest i am confusing with your sending link because ProcessRuntimeService is not in standalone package.

ProcessDefinitionEntity processDefinition = (ProcessDefinitionEntity) repositoryService.getDeployedProcessDefinition(workflowInstance.getProcessDefId());
List activityList = processDefinition.getActivities();

Please suggest how we can get all stage  or node of process definition in Activiti 7.0.0.SR1.

Answer (score 0):

The operations on `Process Definition` can be found in the `RepositoryService`.

You can browse through your BPMN Model using the

`Collection<Resources> myActivtities = this.processEngine.getRepositoryService().getBpmnModel("your_process_definition_id").getResources();`